# What is best release to use with old win xp pro machine?

Tags: system-installation

I have a old Win XP Pro machine that I would like to install Ubuntu on and would like to know what is the best version to get as there are several releases available on Amazon, my go to store. Since this is a 2002 vintage machine I'm assuming one of the older releases is most likely to install without problems.

I built this machine in 2002. It is a 32-bit, Intel P4-D845EBG2L mother board with Pentium 4, 2.2GH, Northwood 512K, Socket 478, 400MHz bus, CPU. It has 1GB of  memory, a ATI All-in-Wonder Radeon 8500DV, 64MB, DDR AGP-Retail, Video card. There are CD, DVD, Floppy and USB 2.0 drives.

My goal is to learn Linux with the Ubuntu release. I have very little knowledge of Linux but have worked with Windows since the DOS days and am some what comfortable at the DOS (windows) command prompt. I admit to drinking the Windows Kool-Aid.

Thanks for any assistance

Greid

Comment: None of currently supported Ubuntu flavors support 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Most Linuxs will let you download their ISOs for free, do not need to buy one, unless you really want to.  They also accept donations, which I doubt they get from Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lubuntu (a fast and lightweight Linux operating system with low hardware requirements) 18.04 which is the last LTS to support 32-bit computers. Click [here](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) and select the 32bit image file for Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

**Note:** 18.04 is only supported until April 2021 and is the last LTS version of Lubuntu that will have 32-bit support.

Comment: 19.04 is out of support and will not get any updates.  OP's best to get another distro that does support 32bit.

Comment: @crip659 thanks, I changed it to 18.04 which is supported to April 2021 and works pretty well on older machines

Comment: Using it on an old P4 myself(sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 was the last LTS with 32 bit support, and it is end of life in 2021. Debian is probably a better bet than Ubuntu in this use case, as they still support 32 bit. If you are going to run a desktop, you will need to stick with something light, LXQT/LXDE or a plain window manager.

That all said, you would better served picking up an inexpensive Raspberry Pi. They are cheap and will perform better than what you have.

Comment: Can upgrade 32bit 16.04 to 18.04, but not to 20.04.

Comment: Tried Debian, no luck. Have Pi4, works. Have win10Pro, happy. Looking for another toy. If I get a 16.04 disc, best guess it would install and have a degree of functionality. Looking mainly to use terminal to educate self with commands. Alternative, build new machine and go big. :-) greid